# Create 2 columns for 2 different group by functions in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql table:

```
team_id match_performance_rating    opponent_rating
1          500                    700
1          400                    625
2          600                    400
3          500                    525
2          400                    200
```

I want to be able to measure the average performance rating for each team (1 to 3) dependant on whether they faced an opponent with a rating > 500 or less than 500 and compare that to the match_performance_rating. So I would compare the value of the row with the value of a group by clause.

The end-result should be something like this:

```
 team_id match_performance_rating  avg_pm_opp_over_500 avg_pm_opp_less_500
    1          500                    450                Null
    1          400                    450                Null
    2          600                    Null               500
    3          500                    500                Null
    2          400                    Null               500
```

I tried to do some type of union query, but it's not creating the extra column:

```
select team_id, pm,pm2 from
(
select team_id,avg(match_performance_rating) as pm
from game_team_rating gtr
where gtr.opponent_rating > 500
group by team_id
union

select team_id as t2,avg(match_performance_rating) as pm2
from game_team_rating gtr
where gtr.opponent_rating < 500
group by team_id) as q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get these averages with conditional aggregation and join the results to the table:

```
select 
  gtr.team_id,
  gtr.match_performance_rating,
  g.avg_pm_opp_over_500,
  g.avg_pm_opp_less_500
from game_team_rating gtr inner join (
  select 
    team_id,
    avg(case when opponent_rating > 500 then match_performance_rating end) avg_pm_opp_over_500,
    avg(case when opponent_rating <= 500 then match_performance_rating end) avg_pm_opp_less_500
  from game_team_rating
  group by team_id  
) g on g.team_id = gtr.team_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9KrSTys8SUYRSKBQ5egjce/1).
Results:

```
| team_id | match_performance_rating | avg_pm_opp_over_500 | avg_pm_opp_less_500 |
| ------- | ------------------------ | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1       | 500                      | 450                 |                     |
| 1       | 400                      | 450                 |                     |
| 2       | 600                      |                     | 500                 |
| 3       | 500                      | 500                 |                     |
| 2       | 400                      |                     | 500                 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions (available in MySQL 8+):

```
select gtr.*
       avg(case when gtr.opponent_rating > 500 then match_performance_rating end) over (partition by gtr.team_id) as pm_over_500,
       avg(case when gtr.opponent_rating < 500 then match_performance_rating end) over (partition by gtr.team_id) as pm_under_500
from game_team_rating gtr;
```