# Combining aggregated grouped values with values for each row based on where conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to compare grouped by values with the values of the individual rows.

Compared to the question I got answered 2 days ago [Create 2 columns for 2 different group by functions in the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56619818/create-2-columns-for-2-different-group-by-functions-in-the-same-table), I now want to be able to only calculate the average rating for the date values that are lower than the date value for the specific row.

Imagine the following table (called game_team_rating)

```
team_id  match_performance_rating    opponent_rating         date
    1            500                      700                2019-05-01
    1            400                      625                2019-05-02
    2            600                      400                2019-05-02
    3            500                      525                2019-05-03
    2            400                      200                2019-05-03
```

The end-result should now be something like this:

```
 team_id   date           match_pr       avg_over_500    avg_less_500
    1      2019-05-01      500             Null               Null
    1      2019-05-02      400             500                Null
    2      2019-05-02      600             Null               Null
    3      2019-05-03      500             Null               Null
    2      2019-05-03      400             Null               400
```

So the avg_over_500 and avg_less_500 columns will only look at the performances from previous matches played.

My thinking was to try code like this:

```
select 
  gtr.team_id,
  gtr.match_performance_rating,
  g.avg_pm_opp_over_500,
  g.avg_pm_opp_less_500
from game_team_rating gtr inner join (
  select 
    team_id,
    avg(case when opponent_rating > 500 and gtr.date > date  then match_performance_rating end) avg_pm_opp_over_500,
    avg(case when opponent_rating <= 500 and gtr.date > date  then match_performance_rating end) avg_pm_opp_less_500
  from game_team_rating
  group by team_id  
) g on g.team_id = gtr.team_id
```

However, this obviously doesnt work because there are no seperation between the date for the grouped values and for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you would use window functions (available in MySQL 8+):

```
select gtr.*
       avg(case when gtr.opponent_rating > 500 then match_performance_rating end) over
           (partition by gtr.team_id order by gtr.date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as pm_over_500,
       avg(case when gtr.opponent_rating < 500 then match_performance_rating end) over
           (partition by gtr.team_id order by gtr.date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as pm_under_500
from game_team_rating gtr;
```

Comment: This almost works, but it includes the current row (I think). I want it to only look at rows with a lower date value.

Comment: @MathiasRa . . . You want a windowing clause, which I added.